# django future feature absloute_import is not defined

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using celery for my project and to call my app at the start I am doing this :

```
from __future__ import absloute_import

from .celery import app as celery_app
```

When I run server it say..

```
future feature absloute_import is not defined
```

I am using python 2.7 and django 1.7 
Whats the issue ??

Answer (score 1):

you misspelled "absolute" :P  you want...

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```